# The intersection of hyperplanes is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

In a book I am reading the author states that "from Linear Algebra we know that the intersection of two hyperplanes of the form $H_i =\{x: a_i^Tx = b_i \}$ for $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is an affine subspace".

If the $b_i$ were $0$ this would be clear to me since then the intersection would be just the kernel of a matrix. But why should this be true for $b_i \ne 0$? Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the claim is not that the intersection is a *vector space*. So claim: If $X$ is a vector space (or just a general affine space) and $A,B\subseteq X$ are affine, then $A\cap B$ is affine.

This follows, since, if $x,y\in A\cap B$ and $t\in \mathbb{R},$ we know that $tx+(1-t)y\in A$ and $tx+(1-t)y\in B$ by assumption, so $tx+(1-t)y\in A\cap B$.

Now, why is a hyperplane affine?

Well, take $x$ and $y$ such that $a^T_ix=a^T_iy=b_i$ and take $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, by linearity,
$$
a_i^T(tx+(1-t)y)=ta_i^Tx+(1-t)a_i^Ty=tb_i+(1-t)b_i=b_i,
$$
proving that a hyperplane is, indeed, affine, even though it is certainly not a subspace of the larger vector space in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not quite get it yet. If I understand you correctly your are proving convextiy and not affinity. But affinity does not imply convexity.

Comment: You mean convexity does not imply affinity. I think I've only seen the two used interchangably so I guess that today I learned. However! You CAN copy the proof above to get that the intersection of affine spaces is again affine. And the calculation below generalises to $t\in \mathbb{R}$, so if you remove the $t\in (0,1)$ clause, everything works just the same, and you should have a proof.